# Stack 2 numeric columns using barplot ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(day=c("one","two","three"),insects=c(50000,25000,12500),ants=c(5000,2500,1250))

    day | insects | ants
 -----------------------
   one     50000   5000
   two     25000   2500
 three     12500   1250
```

I'm trying to plot a graphic like this:

[image]

Where blue bars are the ants and grey bars are the insects. As you can see, ants are always less or equal than insects and also a constitutive part of insects.

My attempt was doing this:

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=day, y=insects, fill=ants))+
     geom_bar(stat="identity")+
     coord_flip()
```

and the result is this (it is obviously wrong):

[image]

I know there are hundreds of questions asking somethig similar, but I can't solve this simple plot. There should be a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
#Melt data
df$day <- factor(df$day,levels = c('one','two','three'),ordered = T)
MD <- melt(df,id.vars = 'day')
#Code
ggplot(data=MD,aes(x=day, y=value, fill=variable))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use a [Stacked barchart](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/48-grouped-barplot-with-ggplot2.html), in wich the subgroups are displayed on top of each other.